# f#: windows form in a compiled program

Tags: .net, f#

To visualize data from F# interactive console, I can do the following:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
let  testgrid (x) =    
          let form = new Form(Visible = true)    
          let data = new DataGridView(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)    
          form.Controls.Add(data)    
          data.DataSource <- x

testgrid [|(1,1);(2,2)|]
```

But if  put the above in a compiled F# program and call `testgrid [|(1,1);(2,2)|]`
 within the program, I only got a freezing window without data. what need to be done to make this `testgrid` works for complied F# program?
**EDIT:** with ildjarn's answer and some search, is the following code ok? Any pitfalls?

```
let testgrid x =
    let makeForm() = 
        use form = new Form()
        new DataGridView(Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource = x) |> form.Controls.Add
        Application.Run form
    let thread = new System.Threading.Thread(makeForm)
    thread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
    thread.Start()
```

Comment: @matlabdbuser - you might be interested in a project I'm working on, FsEye (http://code.google.com/p/fseye/), a WinForms-based visual object tree inspector for FSI.

Comment: @Stephen, THanks for your link. this project is a great tool.

Comment: @Stephen : Awesome, that deserves more exposure.

Comment: @ildjarn - thanks for the feedback. I just posted an announcement on hubFS, http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/23283.aspx, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @matlabdbuser - glad you like it

Comment: @Stephen: Wow, FsEye looks awesome! Would it be difficult to have it in form of a Visual Studio add-on, so the window would be part of the VS?

Comment: @Stephen: i played with fseye yesterday for a bit, and really like it

Comment: @Oldrich - thanks! That's a great idea, and is one of the main things I wanted to investigate before bringing it out of beta status (I've not made a VS add-on before, so I don't know the level of effort).

Comment: @Alex - it's great to hear that. One of the things I enjoy so much about making developer tools, is that I have a strong vision of the features and usability aspects I myself would like to see.

Comment: @matlabdbuser : Regarding your edit, that should be fine as long as you don't call `testgrid` successive times until all threads from prior calls have terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a message pump; FSI already has one, which is why your code works from the FSI console, but a standalone program won't have one unless you make one:

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

let testgrid x =
    use form = new Form()
    new DataGridView(Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource = x) |> form.Controls.Add
    Application.Run form

[<STAThread>]
do testgrid [|(1,1);(2,2)|]
```

Comment: @ildjam, thanks. how to make this function to run in a seperate thread from the main program whenever it is called?

Comment: @matlabdbuser : You are only allowed to have one UI thread per process, so it depends on what your main program does. Does it have a UI also?

Comment: @ildjam,my program does not have aUI. The problem is that if I have code after `do testgrid [|(1,1);(2,2)|]`, it seems the prgram stays on the form and halts to run the following code?

Comment: `Application.Run` does not return until the form window closes.

Comment: @matlabdbuser : If you have no UI at all, you could run `testgrid` in a separate (STA) thread.